# Why is a single exit point for a function preferred?

Tags: coding-style

I have been using multiple return statements in a function for a while and I find it more readable and avoid many conditional blocks. I found many Q & A's suggesting single exit point for a function and I din't find a reasonable explanation for the same. 
Many code analysis tools suggest to have a single exit point for the function.
Can anyone tell me why this approach is preferable?

Thanks

Comment: No code paths exiting the function early, basically. It makes analyzing the program flow easier, but in a world where every call can result in an exception being thrown (and therefore the function returning early), I find this approach less and less useful.